# C - pointer to pointer to structure - segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, segmentation-fault

I learn C pointers, therefore I tried to create array of structs using pointer notation. I allocate array of pointers to struct `User`, I set names and identifiers, then I try to print it and then it crashes.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM    ubuntu:xenial

RUN     apt-get update \
            && apt-get install -y \
                software-properties-common \
                wget \
            && add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test \
            && apt-get update \
            && apt-get install -y \
                make \
                git \
                curl \
                vim \
                vim-gnome \
            && apt-get install -y cmake=3.5.1-1ubuntu3 \
            && apt-get install -y \
                gcc-4.9 g++-4.9 gcc-4.9-base \
                gcc-4.8 g++-4.8 gcc-4.8-base \
                gcc-4.7 g++-4.7 gcc-4.7-base \
                gcc-4.6 g++-4.6 gcc-4.6-base \
            && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 100 \
            && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9 100


COPY ./*.c /tmp/

WORKDIR /tmp/
RUN gcc -Wall main.c -o main

ENTRYPOINT ./main
```

I run my program in docker container because I want to have unused memory.

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_USERS_NUMBER 10

void set_users();
void print_users();

typedef struct User
{
    int id;
    char* username;
} User;

User **users;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    set_users();
    print_users();
    return 0;
}

void set_users()
{
    users = (User **) malloc(MAX_USERS_NUMBER * sizeof(User *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_USERS_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        *(users + i) = (User *) malloc(sizeof(User));
        (*users + i)->id = i;
        (*users + i)->username = (char *) malloc(strlen("username") + 1);
        strcpy((*users + i)->username, "username");
        printf("%d. id: %d, username: %s\n", i, (*users + i)->id, (*users + i)->username);
    }
}

void print_users()
{
    printf("\nUsers\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_USERS_NUMBER; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d. id: %d: ,username: %s\n", i, (*users + i)->id, (*users + i)->username);
    }
}
```

I build image by command:

```
docker build -t gcc-poc .
```

And I run it by command:

```
docker run -it gcc-poc /bin/bash
```

I always get result:

```
0. id: 0, username: username
1. id: 1, username: username
2. id: 2, username: username
3. id: 3, username: username
4. id: 4, username: username
5. id: 5, username: username
6. id: 6, username: username
7. id: 7, username: username
8. id: 8, username: username
9. id: 9, username: username

Users
0. id: 0: ,username: 
1. id: 1: ,username: username
2. id: 2: ,username: username
3. id: 3: ,username: username
Segmentation fault
```

I have read book "Understanding and using C pointers" by O'Reilly but I cannot diagnose the cause.

Comment: `*(users + i)` and `(*users + i)` are not the same thing

Comment: Why did you suddenly change `*(users + i)` to `(*users + i)`? Just use `users[i]` next time if you aren't sure

Comment: The array notation is clearer.

Comment: I wanted to learn pointer notation.

Comment: It's worth noting that using a global to pass around data is an extremely bad habit to get into. A better approach is for the first function to return a pointer that the second can make use of.

Comment: Also, you don't really need `User**`. You can just have `User*` and allocate space for `MAX_USERS_NUMBER * sizeof(User)`.

Comment: There's a time and place for pointer notation, and this isn't it. Use `x[n]` instead of `*(x + n)`. The pointer notation is there for other situations, like `x++` as a very primitive iterator.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya That's true unless you want to be able to easily re-order the list easily. A case can be made for both approaches, but what's shown here is quite confused as to its ultimate intent.

Comment: Has array notation any advantage except of the readability?

Comment: @tadman yes, I agree. But here the struct is probably 16 bytes (twice the size of a pointer). A re-order by value shouldn't be very costly. But yes - it depends on the application. I mentioned it because I think OP got confused because of the double pointer. Had they used `User*`, the present code would have given a compiler error.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yeah, it's a tough call here. I'd argue simplicity first, like you suggest, but there are valid cases for using double pointers.

Comment: *"Has array notation any advantage except of the readability?"* That should be enough, but it's also shorter. The generated code is the same.

Comment: It's best to avoid the phrase "double pointer". It could refer either to a pointer-to-pointer or to the type `double*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `users` is a pointer to pointer to `User`, `*(users + i)` is a pointer to `User` and is proper pointer arithmetic. But `(*users + i)` is not the pointer arithmetic that will produce the result you are looking for.
When a pointer is incremented, the increment will be the size of the type it is pointing to.
For example here:
`users + 1` will increment `users` with `sizeof(User *);` This would be the size of a pointer on your system.

But `*users + 1` will increment `*users` with `sizeof(User)`; This is the size of the `User` structure you have defined.

So you have to change `(*users + i)` to `(*(users + i))` in the code. The extra pair of parenthesis is needed because the `->` operator has higher precedence than `*` operator.

Change your `set_users` and `print_users` functions like this and it will work as intended:

```
void set_users()
{
    users = (User **) malloc(MAX_USERS_NUMBER * sizeof(User *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_USERS_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        *(users + i) = (User *) malloc(sizeof(User));
        (*(users + i))->id = i;
        (*(users + i))->username = (char *) malloc(strlen("username") + 1);
        strcpy((*(users + i))->username, "username");
        printf("%d. id: %d, username: %s\n", i, (*(users + i))->id, (*(users + i))->username);
    }
}

void print_users()
{
    printf("\nUsers\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_USERS_NUMBER; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d. id: %d: ,username: %s\n", i, (*(users + i))->id, (*(users + i))->username);
    }
}
```

Comment: "But (*users + i) is not pointer arithmetic."
This is not true. You also wrote that users is double pointer, so *users is a normal pointer.

Comment: @Mico: Added needed clarifications.

Answer (score -2):

Just try this:

```
#define MAX_CHARS_USERNAME 40

void set_users()
{
    static/*added*/ User* pUser;
    pUser = (User *) malloc(MAX_USERS_NUMBER * sizeof(User));
    users = &pUser;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_USERS_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        (*users + i)->id = i;
        (*users + i)->username = (char *) malloc(MAX_CHARS_USERNAME);
        snprintf((*users + i)->username, MAX_CHARS_USERNAME, "username%d",i);
        printf("%d. id: %d, username: %s\n", i, (*users + i)->id, (*users + i)->username);
    }
}
```

For a pointer to pointer (if needed at all) you might want to use something like `ppUser`.
And do not forget to free the memory (in the reverse order) after usage!

Comment: "*`users = &pUser;`*" assigning to a global pointer the address of a local variable is a bad idea, in fact it does not make sense at all.

Comment: It is a bad idea. And it is wrong. I wonder why this code runs  at all. The function print_users needs actually the storage of pUser which is gone after the function set_users is left!

Comment: I can only imagine that the online compiler (onlinegdb.com) optimized away the double pointer access.
To correct the code, pUser needs to be 'static' or a global. Then the code would be correct, but not good style...

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/HyENZTSOQ
I corrected my example. I still use a double pointer, though actually there is no need for it. I could pass back a normal pointer from set_users.

Comment: Why not *add* the corrected code as per your last comment to your answer?

Comment: To alk: Because stackoverflow suggested it to me.